# Pass a variable in an html template in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to create in a html django template a form with a select dinamically created: I read values from a txt file and I store it in a dict, when I call the render to response I pass this dict but when I try to print its values in the template it doesn't print anything.
This is my views:

```
def home(request):

   i=0
   d = {}
   with open("static/my_file.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
        key=i
        val = line.rstrip()
        d[int(key)] = val
        i=i+1

   return render_to_response('home.html', var=d)
```

and this is the print in the html template:

```
{% for val in var %}
   {{ val.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Can help me?

Comment: Please read docs before asking here.

Comment: All you need to know to fix this (both the view and template) is extensively documented indeed.  And _very_ simple to understand too.

Answer (score 3):

The [Django documentation for `for`-loops in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for) shows that the syntax for dicts is slightly different. Try:

```
{% for key, value in var.items %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of the above jinja file.
If you need just values of `var`, and if `var` is dictionary, then this below code would work for you.

```
{% for val in var.values() %}
   {{ val }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have error in view, you need to pass context as dictionary
    from django.shortcuts import render

```
def home(request):

   i=0
   d = {}
   with open("static/my_file.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
        key=i
        val = line.rstrip()
        d[int(key)] = val
        i=i+1

   return render(request,'home.html', {'var':d})
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? I see the same code, with the only change an import that the OP probably left out to save space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass just the variable or all variable available (local variable) in the view.py to your template just pass locals() in your case should be:

view.py:

```
def home(request):

   i=0
   d = {}
   with open("static/my_file.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
        key=i
        val = line.rstrip()
        d[int(key)] = val
        i=i+1

   return render('home.html', locals())
```

template:

```
{% for key,value in d.items %}
   {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```